# How to say correctly?

Tags: phrase-usage

The question is mostly for native speakers. What is best:

*"Prices for Linux app"* or *"Linux app prices"*

and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Prices for Linux app" or "Linux app prices"

In both your examples, "prices" is plural, "app" is singular.

"Prices for Linux app" is problematic, firstly because it suggests there are multiple prices (plural) for a single app. And if, for some reason, that *is* what you meant - multiple prices for one product - it would be missing an article before "Linux app".

"Linux app prices" is fine. It could be an idiomatic way of referring to the prices (plural) of *any* Linux app, or a range of Linux apps. It doesn't matter that 'app' appears singular.

It could be compared to saying "Greek vacation prices", which could refer to a range of prices of different Greek vacations. But you couldn't say "The prices of Greek Vacation" - you need the plural 'vacations'.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I need to say that by clicking on that link (Let's say "Linux app prices") a customer will be transferred to a page with different prices (depends on a version of an application).
 
So "Linux app prices" is it ok? 
 
Thank you again!

Comment: @OlekNilson If it is just one price for one app, "Linux app *price*" would be right. If it is a page of apps then "prices".

Comment: @Astrabee Thanks!